# Installing another wiki in a new directory on the same domain/server

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki wiki installed under `/wiki` but would like to install another one under `/newwiki`. The wiki configured for `/wiki` works just fine. The problem is that I have the following **Apache configuration** and I am not sure how to add a second wiki since everything is being redirected to `/wiki`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/key.pem

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule (.*) /wiki/ [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wiki/$
    RewriteRule (.*) /wiki/Main_Page [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wiki/index.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding `RewriteRule ^newwiki/(.*)$ /newwiki/$1 [R=301,L]` at the bottom/top but when trying to access `/newwiki` it still redirects to `/wiki`, I did reload Apache. Could someone point me in the right direction please?